# Show message of Image uploaded successfully

Tags: javascript, python, css, flask

**The below is Python Code**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from PIL import Image
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

dic = {0: 'Cat', 1: 'Dog'}

model = load_model('best_model.h5')

model.make_predict_function()


def predict_label(input_image):
    input_image = Image.open(input_image)  # Convert to PIL Image
    input_image = input_image.resize((256, 256))  # Resize the image if needed
    input_image = img_to_array(input_image)
    input_image = preprocess_input(input_image)
    input_image = input_image.reshape(1, 256, 256, 3)
    probabilities = model.predict(input_image)
    class_indices = probabilities.argmax(axis=1)
    predicted_classes = [dic[class_index] for class_index in class_indices]
    class_probabilities = probabilities.tolist()[0]  # Convert to Python list

    return predicted_classes, class_probabilities


# routes
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    return render_template("Frontend.html", message=None)


@app.route("/result", methods=['POST'])
def get_output():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_image = request.files['my_image']

        if uploaded_image:
            # Additional validation for file extension (optional)
            allowed_extensions = {'jpg', 'png'}
            file_extension = uploaded_image.filename.split('.')[-1].lower()

            if file_extension not in allowed_extensions:
                return render_template("Frontend.html", message="Please upload a valid JPG or PNG image.", results=None)

            # Save the uploaded image to the "uploads" folder
            img_filename = 'uploaded_image.jpg'  # You can generate a unique filename if needed
            img_path = os.path.join('uploads', img_filename)
            uploaded_image.save(img_path)

            predicted_classes, class_probabilities = predict_label(img_path)

            # Create a list of class labels and probabilities
            results = [{"class": cls, "probability": prob} for cls, prob in zip(predicted_classes, class_probabilities)]

            # Get the predicted class from the first result
            predicted_class = results[0]["class"]

            # Modify the message based on the prediction
            message = f"Your uploaded image is predicted as: {predicted_class}"

            return render_template("Frontend.html", message=message, img_path=img_path, results=results)

    return render_template("Frontend.html", message="No image selected. Please upload an image.", results=None)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    run_simple('localhost', 9000, app)
```

**Here is the HTML,JS and CSS code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Image Classification Project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Main Image -->
    <img class="image_style" src="D:\MCS\CS619\Project Files\image-classification\templates\Main-Image.jpg">
    <!-- Container For Page -->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Main headline -->
        <h1>Image Classification</h1>

        <!-- Small headline -->
        <p class="Small_headline">Classify Your Image</p><br><hr><br>

        <!-- Small container with instructions -->
        <p class="Small_container">Just Upload the image by clicking on "Upload Image" and classify your uploaded image between <b>Cat or Dog.</b> To get the result, click on "View Result"</p><br><hr><br>

        <!-- Form for uploading image -->
        <form action="/result" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-form">
            <!-- Input element for uploading image -->
            <div class="button-container">
                <!-- Primary button to trigger image upload -->
                <label class="button-primary">
                    Upload Image
                    <input type="file" name="my_image" style="display: none;">
                </label>
                <!-- Secondary button to view the result -->
                <button class="button-secondary" type="button" onclick="viewResult()">View Result</button>
            </div>
        </form>

        <!-- Alert messages -->
        <div id="alert" style="display: none;">
            <div class="warning"><strong id="alert-message"></strong></div>
        </div>

        {% if img_path %}
        <img src="{{ img_path }}" height="400px" width="400px">
        {% endif %}

        {% if message %}
        <h2> Prediction: <i>{{ message }}</i></h2>
        {% endif %}

    </div>

    <!-- JavaScript to handle alerts and validation -->
    <script>
        function showAlert(message, type = 'success') {
            const alertElement = document.getElementById('alert');
            const alertMessageElement = document.getElementById('alert-message');
            alertElement.style.display = 'block';
            alertMessageElement.textContent = message; // Set the alert message text
            setTimeout(() => {
                alertElement.style.display = 'none';
                alertMessageElement.textContent = ''; // Clear the alert message text
                }, 8000);
            }


        function viewResult() {
            const fileInput = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
            if (!fileInput.files.length) {
                showAlert('No image selected. Please upload an image.', 'danger');
            } else {
                document.getElementById('upload-form').submit();
            }
        }

        // Additional validation for file extension (optional)
        document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function () {
            const allowedExtensions = ['.jpg', '.png'];
            const fileName = this.value;
            const fileExtension = fileName.slice(((fileName.lastIndexOf(".") - 1) >>> 0) + 2);

            if (!allowedExtensions.includes(`.${fileExtension.toLowerCase()}`)) {
                showAlert('Please upload a valid JPG or PNG image.', 'danger');
                this.value = ''; // Clear the file input
            }
        });
    </script>
    <!-- CSS for Styling-->
    <style>
    
    /* Container styles */
.container {
    text-align: center; /* Center-align the content within the container */
    margin: 0px auto; /* Center the container horizontally on the page */
    width: 900px; /* Set the width of the container to 900px */
}

/* Main Image styles */
.image_style {
    width: 1250px; /* Set the width of the main image to 1250px */
    height: 500px; /* Set the height of the main image to 500px */
}

/* Small container with instructions styles */
.Small_container {
    text-align: center; /* Center-align the content within the small container */
    margin: 0px auto; /* Center the small container horizontally on the page */
    width: 700px; /* Set the width of the small container to 700px */
    font-size: 18px; /* Set the font size to 18 pixels */
}

/* Small headline styles */
.Small_headline {
    font-size: 18px; /* Set the font size to 18 pixels for the small headline */
}

/* Button container styles */
.button-container {
    text-align: center; /* Center-align the buttons horizontally within the container */
}

/* Primary button styles */
.button-primary {
    display: inline-block; /* Make the primary button inline */
    padding: 16px 40px; /* Set padding for the primary button */
    margin: 15px 200px 15px 0px; /* Set margin for the primary button (top, right, bottom, left) */
    background-color: #0074d9; /* Set the background color of the primary button */
    color: #fff; /* Set the text color of the primary button to white */
    border: none; /* Remove the button border */
    border-radius: 5px; /* Add rounded corners with a radius of 5px */
}

/* Hover effect for primary button */
.button-primary:hover {
    background-color: #379bf4; /* Change the background color on hover */
    cursor: pointer; /* Change the cursor to a pointer on hover */
}

/* Secondary button styles */
.button-secondary {
    display: inline-block; /* Make the secondary button inline */
    padding: 16px 40px; /* Set padding for the secondary button */
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; /* Set margin for the secondary button (top, right, bottom, left) */
    background-color: #0074d9; /* Set the background color of the secondary button */
    color: #fff; /* Set the text color of the secondary button to white */
    border: none; /* Remove the button border */
    border-radius: 5px; /* Add rounded corners with a radius of 5px */
}

/* Hover effect for secondary button */
.button-secondary:hover {
    background-color: #379bf4; /* Change the background color on hover */
    cursor: pointer; /* Change the cursor to a pointer on hover */
}

.warning{
    color: red;
    font-weight: 600;
}

    
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to show the message of "Image uploaded successfully!" When someone uploads a correct image by clicking on "Upload image". Currently there is no such type of message is showing. So, user can't get that image uploaded or not. So, i want to make this situation more clear. Just after uploading image the user should get a message. How can i do that?